# Installed mysql from source on linux and then how to get it work with php?

Tags: linux, apache-http-server, php, mysql

I installed apache and php from source and got them working together a month ago. Because I'm learning both of them this term. 
Now I need mysql to do more works. And I installed mysql from source just now. However I don't know how to let it work with php.
I looked around and found some topics on setting up `LAMP` environment. Most of them install mysql first and use command options `--with-mysql=/usr/local/mysql` and `--with-mysqli=/usr/local/mysql/bin/mysql_config` when installing php. But in my case, I installed php first.
Is there any way to let php know that I have installed mysql? Or should I reinstall php ?

Comment: Try enabling the mysql options on the `php.ini` file and see if that works. But you may need to re-compile php with the `--with-mysql` option rewardless.

Comment: @MartínCanaval could u tell me how to recompile php ? my source is still there.

Comment: It's the same as I suppose you did except this part `./configure --with-mysql && make` Previous and next steps are the same. Oh and maybe pointing to wherever mysql is, like `--with-mysql=/usr/bin/mysql_config --with-mysqli=mysqlnd`

Comment: @MartínCanaval thanx, I know what to do now...

Comment: If everything works out, post an answer to your question and accept it with details of that you did, for others with the same problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I recompiled my php source with appending `--with-mysql=/opt/mysql`, `--with-mysqli=/opt/mysql/bin/mysql_config` and `--with-pdo-mysql` three configure options to let my php support the modules of mysql. Steps taken as follows:
1> stop apache and mysql services 
2> backup php.ini 
3> remove php 
4> reconfigure php source
`./configure --prefix=/opt/php --with-apxs2=/opt/apache/bin/apxs --with-mysql=/opt/mysql --with-mysqli=/opt/mysql/bin/mysql_config --with-pdo-mysql --...and other options` 
5> make and then make install 
6> copy php.ini back and uncomment the corresponding directs on mysql modules